Layout bugging out in a SSRS report when trying to print out as PDF
When working on a report I encountered a really weird problem, and I can't find any article mentioning this issue.
The Report has a pretty simple layout that shows every member under each item code, and each item code in a group that is separated with page breaks.
After previewing the report in SSRS,everything looks completely fine, but when I went on to check the print layout, there is duplicate data showing which messes up the whole report.
e.g when I print the report as PDF, the last member from group item 04 will somehow duplicate a copy and replace the first member for group item 05 which is on the next page, this messes up the report title making it show item 04 as the title for group item 05, every other part of the report is working as intended with only 04,05 bugging out.
This problem does not happen when I view the report in the preview layout, only when I print out the report as PDF, so I am not sure if the problem is caused by me doing something wrong or if there is something wrong with my SSRS.
Removing the page break for the group for item_code makes it normal, also printing the report as CSV or XML which doesn't includes page breaks shows the data in the correct layout. Printing the report as Excel or PDF breaks it, so I'm expecting that there is something wrong with the whole page break thing that messes up the report when I try to print it.

It's hard to say without seeing the design but I've had similar issues (maybe twice in 20 years), that I never got to the bottom of. I think I had to play around with the design slightly (adding a blank row at the end of a group etc.). Not very scientific but it worked.
